# javafx printing API, Simple Text Print

Tags: javafx, printing

I am looking for a way to print text from a TextArea using javafx 8 Printing API. So far every tutorial I come across is talking about printing NODES, which I find to be ground breaking and was wowed when I tried it, such awesome power but I need to simply print Text from a TextArea.

Thanks Inadvance

Comment: Completed the task using AWT Printing API, but the question still remains how is javafx 8 implement the same

Comment: Why not just create a `Text` node with the same text as the text area, and print it?

Comment: Works like a charm, just needs a good formatting of the lendered page otherwise the text appears stretched. Thanks James